# Distinct() in Map/Transform

Tags: indexing, mapreduce, distinct, ravendb

I have the following index I'm creating in order to get all the permissions for a specific user. In the transform, `roles.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions)` could contain duplicates, so I want to put `.Distinct()` on it. However, when I do, it seems to get translated to `Enumerable.Distinct(roles.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions)` inside of Raven, which returns no results. If I change the index directly in Raven to use `.Distinct()` instead of `Enumerable.Distinct(...)`, it works perfectly.

How can this be written so that it gets translated properly in Raven?

```
public class PermissionsByUser : AbstractIndexCreationTask<User, UserWithPermissions>
{
    public override string IndexName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Users/PermissionsByUser";
        }
    }
    public PermissionsByUser()
    {
        Map = users => from user in users
                       from role in user.Roles
                       select new {role.Id};

        TransformResults = (database, users) => from user in users
                                                let roles = database.Load<Role>(user.Roles.Select(x => x.Id))
                                                select new
                                                        {
                                                            Id = user.Id,
                                                            Username = user.Username,
                                                            Password = user.Password,
                                                            Roles = user.Roles,
                                                            Permissions = roles.SelectMany(x => x.Permissions)//.Distinct()
                                                        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was, I think, actually just a problem of stale results. Answered at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ravendb/0hO8TOQicwc